# Android: FragmentTabHost Widget not displaying Title

Tags: java, android, xml

Im trying to design a custom TabWidget with FragentTabHost following these two guides for the tab layout:

https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/android-styling-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

http://joshclemm.com/blog/custom-android-tabs/

Im building FragmentTabHost with three fragments, the first fragment have a expandable list view.

Everything works fine, i can set backgroundcolor, the icon (if i want to) and the indicator works as well, as the divider does(if i want to) but the **tabtitle does not appear** for some reason and i cant find the reason why it dont show up.

If i remove **tab_indicator.xml** from **android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator"** in **tab_layout.xml** and set the backgroundcolor to whatever color the tab title shows up, but then i obviuosly dont get the indicators.

Do anyone have a clue whats wrong and what im missing. I have tried to solve this problem and searching för some days now and it starts to get very frustrating because its seems like something simple.

**tab_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**tab_indicator.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Non focused states-->
    <item  android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
    <item  android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
    <!-- Focused states-->
    <item    android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
    <item    android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
     <!-- Pressed-->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_pressed" />
    <item  android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_pressed" />
</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:showDividers="middle"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

**tab_selected.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <item android:top="-7dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:left="-7dp" android:right="-7dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:left="10dp"
                android:top="15dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="15dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FF00ccff" />
            <solid android:color="#2fff00"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, if i change android:layout_height in FragmentTabHost and TabWidget it displays the text, simple as that. But in my tast the height is to big ^^ I want it to be smaller like 35dp and it can be done if i change the padding in tab_selected.xml, _unselected and _pressed, and then i can change the height in TabWidget activity_main.xml else the text wont fit the tab.